# Getting Trying to get property * of non-object when using get_results in WordPress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have two tables that have a one-to-one relationship. one of them is `wp_posts` and `wp_books` Now I want to get post that related to specif book with this code:

```
function column_default($item, $column_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'post':
            $post_query =  "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE id = {$item->post_id} 
             AND post_type='books' LIMIT 1 ";
            $post = $wpdb->get_results($post_query, OBJECT);
            return $post->post_title;
        default:
            return $item;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object

What's wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that get_results actually returns an array (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) therefore you are trying to read 'post_title' from an array which doesn't have that property and in fact it is an array, not an object.

You should use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#select-a-row "**get_row**" for that